# what constitutes "large amount of write activity" for Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am currently working on an online ordering application using Mongodb as the backend.  In looking into sharding, the [Mongo docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding/) say that you should consider sharding if

"your system has a large amount of write activity, a single MongoDB instance cannot write data fast enough to meet demand, and all other approaches have not reduced contention."

So my question is:  what constitutes a large amount of write activity?  are we talking 1000's of writes per second?  100's?

I know that sharding introduces a level of infrastructure complexity that I'd rather not get into if I don't have to.

thanks!

R

Comment: it will depend highly on the hardware you select - disk speed, etc. also the size of the writes (size of your documents you insert, size of updates you make).  My laptop can do tens of thousands per second but I may have completely different document size than you will and my laptop is very different machine than your server(s) will be.

Comment: thanks. documents will be small as will the updates.  even in best case scenario we won't be anywhere near 10,000's per second.

Comment: it doesn't sound like you will need sharding, at least not till you grow the app significantly?

Answer (score 0):

The "large amount of write activity" is not defined in terms of a specific number .. but rather when your common usage pattern exceeds the resources of your server hardware.  For example, when average I/O flush time or iowait indicates that I/O has become a significant limiting factor.

You do have other options to consider before sharding:

- if your working set is larger than RAM and you have significant page faults, upgrade your RAM
- if your disk I/O isn't keeping up, consider upgrading to faster disks, RAID, or SSD
- review and adjust your [readahead](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Notes#ProductionNotes-Readahead) settings
- look into [optimization](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimization) of slow or inefficient queries
- review your indexes and remove unnecessary ones